# when extract value from xml, textbox doesn't take double spaces

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml

I have an xml file like this:

```
<Product ID="1"  Code="AAAA AA"  Price="10"/>
<Product ID="2"  Code="AAAA  AA" Price="20"/>
```

I load 'Code' into  tag

```
$('#select1').append($('<option></option>').val('1').html($(this).attr('Code')));
```

and I compare the value of select1 and the value from XML path:

```
function()
{ 
  var e = document.getElementById('textbox1');
  var proValue= e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
  if($(this).attr('Code')==proValue)
  {
    var proPrice = $(this).attr('Price'); 
    document.getElementById('textfbox2').value=proPrice; 
  }
}
```

The problem is that `$(this).attr('Code')==proValue` returns false with ID='2' as the value of it has two spaces.
However, it works fine with the one with ID='1'.

Any ideas of how can I fix it?

Comment: Out of curiosity... why does it have double spaces?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the space character instead of typing the actual space.
    `&#032;` or `&nbsp;`
It has worked for me in the past with similar problems.